# Splitting a DoB column of a pandas DataFrame in the format of 'Nov 4, 1992 (27)' to get a DoB as a datetime

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame of scraped data. For the `dob` column, the records are in the following format:

Nov 4, 1992 (27)

I need split the string  to create a date of birth column in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy' e.g. 04/11/1992. I will take the split string and convert using the pd.to_datetime() function.

I would also like to create an age column e.g. 27. A more elegant solution using the current date and time instead of the string split would be great.

I've come up with a few of my own solutions but I'm sure this could be done more elegantly using a regex expression or similar.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to extract the date and the age, then convert them to your intended data types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': ['Nov 4, 1992 (27)']})

df[['Date', 'Age']] = df['DOB'].str.extract(r'(.+) \((\d+)\)')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'])
```

Comment: Yeah that RegEx did the trick. I'll now work creating an age column using the current date and the new 'date' column, as opposed to the string extract. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the age from the date, for comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()

df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': ['Nov 4, 1992 (27)']})
df[['Date', 'Age']] = df['DOB'].str.extract(r'(.+) \((\d+)\)')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Calculated Age'] = df['Date'].apply(
               lambda x: today.year - x.year - 
               ((today.month, today.day) < (x.month, x.day)) 
               )
```